Ansible Automation Platform not Syncing with Gitlab project
AAP 2.4 Project not syncing GitLab using PAT and my error is
SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain.

I really don’t want to disable https and not sure if I download the .pem from the browser that is pointing to the gitlab repo.
Not sure what ca bundle in redhat docs is talking about or find it to download.
In AAP there is this parameter:
EXTRA ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES:

{
 "GIT_SSL_CAINFO": "/etc/custom-ca/bundle-ca.crt"
}

Should I download pem from my Gitlab site pointing to my repository?
Add pem to my trusted certs in AAP?
Thanks for any guidance
